# How to override DISTRO_VERSION?

Tags: yocto

I'm populating an sdk using the command `bitbake <image> -c populate_sdk` and the resulting *.sh installer file has an version number which is the same as the `DISTRO_VERSION`. (yocto poky)

I tried to override the `DISTRO_VERSION` in build/conf/local.conf, but it does not override the existing DISTRO_VERSION, I do not understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change SDK version, you need to use [SDK_VERSION](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-SDK_VERSION) variable defined in `poky` as:

```
SDK_VERSION = "${@d.getVar('DISTRO_VERSION').replace('snapshot-${DATE}','snapshot')}"
```

Comment: At the time my problem was that I tried to overwrite what was writen ( SDK_VERSION = "") in distro configuration. Which does not work, after changing it to an weak override in the distro configuration I can change it in local.conf. We need different sdk names for official and non official releases.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but how about creating a variable on local.conf:

```
MY_INSTALLER_VER = "XX.XX.XX"
```

And attribute it at `your_customized_distro.conf`:

```
DISTRO_VERSION = "${MY_INSTALLER_VER}"
```

I've tried on warrior release and it worked.

Comment: yes this will also work, but previously explained the variable was set by a distro layer configuration with = "YY.YY.YY" and i didnt had a own distro.conf so it was not possible to overwrite it.  But your answer will work of course. thanks